# Create CSV Table and write to a CSV File - Missing Double Quotes

Tags: office-365, flow, power-automate

I am trying to write a CSV file from a flow, I have an array of JSON objects.

[image]

Output is

[image]

I want something like this, I want to all fields in double quote.

[image]

I have more than 50 columns in total, some have numbe4rs, text, multiple text and dates, I am showing only 2 columns in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Select] action to concatenate double quote (") to the input values coming from your list.

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

**Expressions used in [Select] action**

```
outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']

concat('"', item()?['LastName'], '"')

concat('"', item()?['FirstName'], '"')

concat('"', item()?['Email'], '"')
```

**Final Output in the attached CSV sent to email**
[image]